# Does Javascript support the ability to get a directory listing?

Tags: javascript, http, ftp, directory, jpeg

I want to upload a bunch of image files to a directory that I've set up on my ISP's free hosting service. It's something like http://home.ISPname.net/~username/subdir.

I want my Javascript code to be able to get a directory listing and then preload whatever it finds.

But getting such a thing even possible? My impression is not.

I suspect I will have to instead rename my files to 00000.jpg and upward, and attempt to detect what files are there using try.

FYI, I know that my ISP does not support using FTP protocol to get a directory listing.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you enable the web server's directory listing in `/subdir`?

Comment: No, it's my ISP's server so I have no control over permissions or server capabilities. Mind you, I did try paying for hosting once from GoDaddy.com; that was a huge disaster, so now I'm going with free hosting.

Comment: Free hosting is not worth it. For $5/month you can get an acceptable host. (Plus the domain cost)

Answer (score 3):

Under the assumption that your JavaScript code is code on your pages and not code on your server, then no, there's no API provided *for JavaScript in a web browser* other than a server-side API accessible via HTTP that you would create yourself. If the directory full of files is on the server, then it's going to have to be some server-side code that delivers the directory listing anyway.  You could write such code in the server-side programming environment of your choice (including a server-side JavaScript solution, if that's what you want and if such a thing is possible at your ISP). As Pekka notes, it may be possible to simply enable directory browsing in your server, though that's generally a fairly low-level service that will deliver some sort of HTML page to you, and parsing through that might be somewhat painful (compared to what you could get from a tailor-made service).

Another, simpler thing you could do would be to upload a manifest file along with the other image files.  In other words, create the directory listing in some easy-to-digest form, and maintain it separately as a simple file to be fetched.

Comment: I thought about the manifest idea, it's a good one because it would let me add keywords alongside the filenames. But it also represents just one more step that I have to take to get my files onto the server :(

Comment: Well maybe you could encapsulate the manifest generation with a script that uploads from your build tree to the site?

Answer (score 0):

javascript **not suport** directory listing in a direct way. but you can create a directory dumper php file, and send via AJAX.

Comment: I'm using freebie hosting from my ISP, so there is no PHP or any other scripting ability, other than client-side JS.